# How would I set the max amount of times an int can appear from a random number generator?

Tags: java, random, numbers

Say if I randomly generated 30 numbers from 1 to 50 but for example I didn't want 4 to occur more than 3 times at most, or 23 to occur more than once. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you could use a map<integer, bool> and create mapping for each time you generate the number. then check your map if it exists, if it doesn't exist you can use that number, if it does exist in the map then generate another random number.

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want.  Are you simulating a random draw without replacement (so that the overall pool shrinks as you draw numbers) or are you just refusing to accept more than x occurrences of a given number?  The implementation and the distribution of results differ between those cases.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, I don't see any conflict between the OP's proposed program and randomness.  The resulting numbers will not be uniformly distributed, but that's an entirely separate thing.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I really don't understand what OP wants, obviously we could fill a pool with `int`(s) and then shuffle it and draw. But why 3 fours and only one 23?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, it beats me why the OP wants what he described.  That's why I asked him.  I'm just observing that contrary to the implication of your first comment, there's no reason to think that what he's after is somehow non-random.

Comment: @JohnBollinger *I didn't want 4 to occur more than 3 times at most, or 23 to occur more than once* implies a distinct lack of randomness to me (it would fail at least one die hard test for example), but I **may** be reading too much into the sentence.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, as I said, that's about the distribution from which the joint result is drawn, not about whether the joint result or its individual components are random.  *Random* does not imply *uniformly distributed*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ahhh, but what is the *probability* of the second (or third or fourth) of our thirty drawn numbers being the value 4? We want thirty random numbers between 1 and 50. Except some of the numbers cannot be 4 or 23 after some arbitrary number of occurrences. That *might* effect how random the next value truly is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random();
List<int> randoms = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
    int num = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    if (num == 23 && randoms.contains(23)) {
        i--;
        break;
    }
    if (num == 4 &&  Collections.frequency(randoms, 4) >= 3) {
        i--;
        break;
    }
    randoms.add(num);
}
```

Comment: And just how is that "not really random anymore"?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Map. If you haven't used a Map before, check [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) out.

Then you could implement something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for(...)
{
    //#Generate Random Number#//
    Integer occur = occurrences.get(randNum);
    occurrences.put(randNum, (occur == null) ? 1 : occur + 1);

    if(occurrences.get(randNum) > occurrenceLimit)
    {
        //#Generate a different random number and try again#//
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using pseudocode

```
//initialize a list
Collection numbers;
for i = some min value; i < desired max number; i++
    numbers.add(i)

Integer grabRandomNumber()
{
    //now generate a random INDEX based on the size of your collections list
    index = randomNumber(0, numbers.size() - 1)

    //Now go to that index and grab that number
    numberYouWant = numbers.get(index)
    //BUT you should remove the number you retrieved so the next time
    //you try and grab a number you won't grab a duplicate
    numbers.remove(index)

    //then just return the number you got
    return numberYouWant
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** 
*(most basic, but inefficient)*

You can use an integer array with the size of the bounds you are using for your integers (or a Hashanah with Integer to Integer for large ranges) and every time a number appears you increment the integer value.

Then when looping you check if the returned value has exceeded it's limit of uses and get another value and repeat.

**Method 2**

There is a second method which can be better than the first as when there is only one value possible out of 100 numbers the method could repeat many times before one result.
What you do is use a 
HashMap of Integer to Integer.
You then put all possible values as keys into it with their limits of returns (and a flag for no limit) as the values.
You then generate a random number from 0 to the HashMap size - 1 and get the corresponding index in the keySet if the HashMap and decrement the value related to the key until it is 0 and then you remove the value.

**Example:**

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
Random r = new Random();

while( map.size() > 0){
     int index =r.nextInt (map.size());
     int key = map.keySet().get(index);
     map.put(key, map.get(key)-1);
     if( map.get(key) == 0){
          map.remove(key);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, putting restrictions on this kind of thing somewhat defeats the whole definition of **random**.

That said, you can count the number of times each number is generated and check the count against whatever rules you need before returning the latest figure.

Comment: "Defeats the definition of random"? Baloney.  The numbers drawn in a trial such as the OP describes are not *uniformly distributed*, but that's quite a different thing than being non-random.